Почему возникает ошибка "peer id invalid"? (pyrogram)
при получении сообщения из некоторых каналов постоянно ловится ошибка
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future:  exception=ValueError('Peer id invalid: -1002266047364')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\novikov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\resolve_peer.py", line 62, in resolve_peer      
    return await self.storage.get_peer_by_id(peer_id)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\novikov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\storage\sqlite_storage.py", line 142, in get_peer_by_id
    raise KeyError(f"ID not found: {peer_id}")
KeyError: 'ID not found: -1002266047364'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\novikov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py", line 569, in handle_updates
    channel=await self.resolve_peer(utils.get_channel_id(channel_id)),
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\novikov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\resolve_peer.py", line 89, in resolve_peer      
    peer_type = utils.get_peer_type(peer_id)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\novikov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\utils.py", line 246, in get_peer_type
    raise ValueError(f"Peer id invalid: {peer_id}")
ValueError: Peer id invalid: -1002266047364
DEBUG:pyrogram.session.session:Received: {
    "_": "Message",
    "msg_id": 7449463490663309313,
    "seq_no": 161,
    "length": 328,
    "body": {
        "_": "types.Updates",
        "updates": [
            {
                "_": "types.UpdateNewChannelMessage",
                "message": {
                    "_": "types.Message",
                    "id": 11016,
                    "peer_id": {
                        "_": "types.PeerChannel",
                        "channel_id": 2266047364
                    },
                    "date": 1734463378,
                    "message": "ГО В ЛС???",
                    "out": false,
                    "mentioned": false,
                    "media_unread": false,
                    "silent": false,
                    "post": true,
                    "from_scheduled": false,
                    "legacy": false,
                    "edit_hide": false,
                    "pinned": false,
                    "noforwards": false,
                    "reply_to": {
                        "_": "types.MessageReplyHeader",
                        "reply_to_msg_id": 10399,
                        "reply_to_scheduled": false,
                        "forum_topic": false
                    },
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "_": "types.MessageEntityTextUrl",
                            "offset": 0,
                            "length": 10,
                            "url": "https://t.me/Molnia_RoBot?start=tomichkinZaliv"
                        }
                    ],
                    "views": 1,
                    "forwards": 0,
                    "restriction_reason": []
                },
                "pts": 22040,
                "pts_count": 1
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "_": "types.User",
                "id": 136817688,
                "is_self": false,
                "contact": false,
                "mutual_contact": false,
                "deleted": false,
                "bot": true,
                "bot_chat_history": false,
                "bot_nochats": false,
                "verified": false,
                "restricted": false,
                "min": true,
                "bot_inline_geo": false,
                "support": false,
                "scam": false,
                "apply_min_photo": true,
                "fake": false,
                "bot_attach_menu": false,
                "premium": false,
                "attach_menu_enabled": false,
                "bot_can_edit": false,
                "access_hash": 1953598452476464818,
                "first_name": "Channel",
                "username": "Channel_Bot",
                "photo": {
                    "_": "types.UserProfilePhoto",
                    "photo_id": 587627495930570665,
                    "dc_id": 1,
                    "has_video": false,
                    "personal": false,
                    "stripped_thumb": "b'\\x01\\x08\\x08\\xb1\\xf2\\xf9_\\xedg4QEp3\\xad\\x1f'"
                },
                "bot_info_version": 4,
                "restriction_reason": [],
                "usernames": []
            }
        ],
        "chats": [
            {
                "_": "types.Channel",
                "id": 2266047364,
                "title": "Милана",
                "photo": {
                    "_": "types.ChatPhoto",
                    "photo_id": 5325865610497878015,
                    "dc_id": 2,
                    "has_video": false,
                    "stripped_thumb": "b'\\x01\\x08\\x08\\x8a7_1\\t\\xec\\x0fz(\\xa2\\xaa\\x1b\\x17c'"
                },
                "date": 1732041385,
                "creator": false,
                "left": false,
                "broadcast": true,
                "verified": false,
                "megagroup": false,
                "restricted": false,
                "signatures": false,
                "min": true,
                "scam": false,
                "has_link": false,
                "has_geo": false,
                "slowmode_enabled": false,
                "call_active": false,
                "call_not_empty": false,
                "fake": false,
                "gigagroup": false,
                "noforwards": false,
                "join_to_send": false,
                "join_request": false,
                "forum": false,
                "access_hash": -1192020165435594607,
                "restriction_reason": [],
                "usernames": []
            }
        ],
        "date": 1734463379,
        "seq": 0
    }
}
